# How to measure the max size of the largest character in a given font type and font size?

Tags: ios, fonts

I want to cache some textures of characters of a given font type and font size, but I can't make sure of the max size the largest char may take in the whole unicode char set.

How can I calculate this size?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437567/measure-dimensions-of-biggest-character-in-a-cgfont

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Font Bounding Box (or BBox). In iOS, you'll need a CGFontRef and can then use the function:

```
CGRect CGFontGetFontBBox (
   CGFontRef font
);
```

This returns the font bounding box, which is the union of all glyph bounding boxes in the font. It returns the value in *glyph units*.

Comment: Thank you David, thanks so much! This is what I want. That's great!

Comment: When I debug my app time and time again, I found that the font size value passed in to API is just the max height the char could take actually, eg: fontsize = 24, then the char size in pixel may be {14,24} ... {21, 24} .. {9, 24}, though the width is changing, but height is still 24. I'm not sure whether it's just a coincidence or not. What do you think about this?

Comment: sorry, just a moment ago, I tried setting the font size = 50, then the height is 59 : <.  Haha.  But maybe the width is never gonna be greater than height? I just guess.

Comment: Yes, in general I think you'll find values lower than or around the point size, but there are definitely characters that have low descenders or high ascenders as you have just found :) Point size is a good indication of the size of text of course, but it doesn't take exceptions into account.

Comment: OK, THANK YOU. I think I can use a fixed value eg:fontsize=26, as my experiment shown, at most time the actual drawn char size is less than 31, when I found the size is greater than 31 (or the bound size  32), I redraw the char using smaller font size, till its drawn size is less than the bound size. This may fix the problem. Since the drawing op couldn't happen frequently, the performance should be acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

well, you may use sizeWithFont:

and check the largest (or tallest or biggest in area)

it works well for width and area, but it seems that all characters have got the same height, even dots "."

anyway, i guess that something like that should answer your question:

```
UIFont* aFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:15];
NSString* charsToTest = @"abcdf...xyz, ABCD...XYZ, 0123...";
float maxArea = 0;
float maxWidth = 0;
float maxHeight = 0;
NSString* largerChar;
NSString* tallerChar;
NSString* biggerChar;
for (int i = 0; i<charsToTest.length; i++) {
    NSRange currentRange;
    currentRange.length = 1;
    currentRange.location = i;
    NSString* currentCharToTest = [charsToTest substringWithRange:currentRange];
    CGSize currentSize = [currentCharToTest sizeWithFont:aFont];
    if (currentSize.width > maxWidth) {
        maxWidth = currentSize.width;
        largerChar = currentCharToTest;
        NSLog(@"char:%@, new record width: %f", largerChar, maxWidth);
    }
    if (currentSize.height > maxHeight) {
        maxHeight = currentSize.height;
        tallerChar = currentCharToTest;
        NSLog(@"char:%@, new record height:%f", tallerChar, maxHeight);
    }
    float currentArea = currentSize.height * currentSize.width;
    if ( currentArea > maxArea) {
        maxArea = currentArea;
        biggerChar = currentCharToTest;
        NSLog(@"char:%@, new area record: %f", biggerChar, maxArea);
    }
}
// final resut:
NSLog(@"\n\n");
NSLog(@"char:%@ --> MAX WIDTH IS: %f", largerChar, maxWidth);
NSLog(@"char:%@ --> MAX HEIGHT IS: %f", tallerChar, maxHeight);
NSLog(@"char:%@ --> MAX AREA IS: %f\n\n", biggerChar, maxArea);
```

Comment: Apart from taking a long time, this will only test those specific characters in the string you give it. That is far from "the max size the largest char may take in the whole unicode char set" as specified in the question. The font bounding box was invented specifically to answer this question for large font sets (it's a cache of the calculation you suggest here for the complete character set supported by the font if you want).

Comment: the problem with CGFontGetFontBBox is that it return a CGRect not in pixel: "The value is specified in glyph space units", and i'm not sure it's enough for the original question. For the list of chars... sure, i just focused my answer to the size aspect, it's not such a big problem to get the wanted list...

Comment: glyph space units are the only sensible units this can return - all you have to do is take the point size into account afterwards. And it's a really big problem to use your approach because the question speaks specifically about the complete Unicode set. Do you know how many characters you can have in a Unicode font? I doubt you want to make a couple of thousand calls to sizeWithFont. I'm sorry, but your approach is not the correct one.

Comment: dear David, i see your point of view, but, reading the original question: "I want to cache some textures of characters..." Don't you think that he's going to loop all chars anyway, saving texture for each char? Do you really thing that adding a sizeWithFont: to his loop could slow down so much his method?

Comment: There's no way of telling what iOS must do to get the width of each character you present it. At best it will load lots of information for each character, at worst it will render the character (but if they're smart there won't). It's besides the point even, the font BBox has been invented specifically to answer the question of the size of the union of all character bounding boxes - it's there for a reason. Not to mention that doing one call plus a metric conversion is certainly more maintainable and elegant code. Sorry, it's not because your code is possible, that it's also advisable.

Comment: Thanks everybody, thank you so much! To meronix: I wanna cache textures that the char is going to be drawn on screen ,so I cannot know what char would be cached until runtime, so I need to prepare for the whole char set, include chinese char set ..., so try get the size one by one seems thicky and may works , but I still wanna get the answer by system API, if it could.  To David: Your Approach is almost what I want, but I'm busy these days, so I havn't tried this approach. from the comment I saw that the BBox size need to tranform to pixel size, hope I can figure it out. Thank you so much!